# How to add Google Drive in Debian KDE

Tags: linux, debian, kde, google

there is an error when you connect Google Drive via Network. How do I fix it and connect the disk in KDE?[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a description of the steps you're taking before you run into this error?

Comment: I go to Dolphin, click on Network, select Google Drive, then I enter my mail and then this error occurs.